# How to create a floating menu with a sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, submenu

I am looking for a floating menu like the on found on the right side of the screen on [this](http://themeforest.net) page.

I have been able to create a floating menu like the one found [here](http://www.allwebco-templates.com/support/S_script_floating.htm)

But I want a menu to pop up on clicking on the link available.

Looked in some of the previous questions but none of them matched what I required.

Answer (score 0):

Choose what's best suits u..

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Comment: There is no floating menu....on the link
I am looking for floating menu like the one here [http://themeforest.net/](http://themeforest.net/) with the sub-menus